# Flutter searchfield conectar con api

Tags: flutter

Me gustaria saber como conectar un API con el --searchfield-- ya que de momento en la documentacion no comprendo del todo de como funciona, solo de forma local con datos quemados

```
    final List<String> _suggestions = ['Equipo', 'Marca', 'Modelo'];
```

y este serial el que normalmente tiene la documentacion, mas no logro conectarlo a un api como el
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums

```
SearchField(
            controller: con.etiqueta,
            suggestionState: Suggestion.expand,
            suggestionAction: SuggestionAction.next,
            suggestions:
                _suggestions.map((e) => SearchFieldListItem(e)).toList(),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            //controller: _searchController,
            hint: 'Etiqueta',
            // initialValue: SearchFieldListItem(_suggestions[2], SizedBox()),
            maxSuggestionsInViewPort: 3,
            itemHeight: 45,
            onSuggestionTap: (x) {},
          ),
```

Comment: ¿No lo consigues hacer o no lo has intentado siquiera? Unos consejillos: pregunta en So cuando hayas hecho búsquedas e intentado resolver el problema que tienes. provee siempre que sea posible el código de lo que llevas intentado. En el código que has expuesto, no hay nada relativo a qué has intentado. Agrega siempre que sea posible enlaces a los packages que estés usando, en este caso el package de SearchField.

Answer (score 0):

[Este enlace de la documentación oficial te puede ayudar a aclarar tus dudas](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Tendrías que cambiar el response de tu fetch data a una lista de tu Objeto, e iterar para listar todos los objetos, y en el FutureBuilder si recibes data en vez de retornar el Text() del ejemplo retorna tu SearchFiled, por lo que veo en tu *suggestions* tienes que devolver una lista de SearchFieldListItem(String) y el parámetro que necesitas es un String así que eso lo manejas según cómo regrese tu snapshot.data y le pasas el String.